# How can I hook into the system Contact form Message Sent process and alter the HTML generated?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a Drupal site where I am using the sited-wide system Contact to allow visitors to send messages to the site owner.  Once a visitor submits the form, the user is redirected to the home page and a sticky appears at the top reading:

**Your message has been sent.**

My question then, is it possible to change this message and add some HTML to the output?  Ideally I would add some javascript to create a virtual page view for the Google Analytics account so that I can track it as a Goal Conversion.

I imagine this would be a hook_ function sitting in my template file, but I'm relatively new to this process.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, just use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) and add a callback to $form['#submit']. The easiest way to find your form's id is inspecting it using firebug. This article has a lot more detailed info: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6.

In short:

- Find the id for the contact form, "contact_mail_page" or something (notice how hifens turn to underscores)
- In a new custom module implement either: `yourmodule_form_alter($form_id, &$form, 'contact_mail_page')` or `yourmodule_form_contact_mail_page_alter($form_id, &$form)`
- Modify the contact form as you want using the $form variable passed by reference

Comment: thanks for your response.  I've read through that article and I'm no closer to this solution.  Do you have an example? That article shows how to write a hook for a module, but the Contact form is a system module so if I make the change their then a core update would blow that change away.  Maybe I'm still missing something.

Comment: I've edited the first post to include more details

Comment: thanks for the update.  I'm still not clear on how to implement your solution.  So I create a new module and put the code where?  As I mention above, I'm new enough to Drupal that I've never had to write a module. Maybe I should just use that webform module.  Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module might be more suited to your needs if it's just a general site wide form.

Comment: I meant to add... the webform module allows you to specify a redirect url which is used when the form is successfully submitted. This also means you can manage the success page easily as a regular content type.

Hope this helps.

James

Answer (score 0):

@shanabus, you're understanding of "write a hook for a module" is incorrect. The main goal of creating a custom hook for any existing module including a system module is to over-ride the behaviour. This is how you customise Drupal to a specific sites needs. You'll not edit the existing code but rather add new code that uses the "hook" system to add new/replacement functionality.

Typically a custom hook function lives in a custom module created specifically for the site by the author of the site. Consider it a place to store your site specific customisations that you'll not be sharing with the greater Drupal community. A classic use would be a hook_form_alter as Alex suggests above.

Consider looking at the hook API documentation for more details: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks. This is often a concept that new Drupal developers struggle with so don't be discouraged if it takes some extra effort to get the concept figured out. We've all been here :)